# can't retrieve images with img src with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm working in local using WAMP, the structure of my website root folder is this:

MySite

- *Images*

  - image1.png
  - image2.jpeg
  - ...

  Directory1

  - file1.php
  - *file2.php*

  Directory2

  - file3.php
  - file4.php

Well, I'm into *file2.php* and I would retrieve some of the images inside the directory 'Images'.
I tried in several ways but I failed everytime.

Comment: copy the code you've written so far here and somebody will help you to fix it !

Comment: Please provide code and understandable directory structure...

Answer (score 1):

The relative file path in your case should include a link to one level above your current page. To access the images in the structure you posted, use:

```
<img src="../images/myimage.jpg" />
```

Note the .., which tell the web server to seek the image one level above, and then go into the image dir.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `../images/[name of image]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a relative path like:

`../images/<image filename>`

Or with an absolute path to wherever the `images` directory belongs. E.g.:

`C:\wamp\www\<...>\images\<image filename>`

I recomend the first way because if you happen to move the website directory to somewhere else it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

In your file2.php

```
//Read the file in binary
$imagen = file_get_contents('image1.png');

//Convert the binary to Base64 (string of numbers a chars)
$imageData = base64_encode($imagen);

//retrive the string
echo $imageData
```

And to call the image

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64, <?PHP include 'file2.php' ?>'/>;
```